# Conversion of InputStream into String in Android returning partial string of response. Can some one suggest why it could be?

Tags: android, inputstream

In below code, I have a problem for converting a response Input Stream received from server as its not giving me full length response string.

I am using Google Places service mentioned below which even if hit in browser or any other external HTTP Client returns a full length response but in case of Android when I am using below method it returns some part of response only. Can some one suggest why it could be? Is it because of buffer size or there are some other reasons associated with it.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=18.5203,73.8567&radius=1000000&key=AIzaSyA9iyRrod8WpOcaWYXiGiNfkGpAHW16jcM

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;

    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                            
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```